# Wsapi data store query

Tags: rally

I am looking to get all projects under a selected project (i.e the entire child project branch ) using Wsapi data store query in Rally SDK 2.0rc1. Is it possible using a query to recursively get all child project names? or will I have to write a separate recursive function to get that information? If a separate recursive function is required, how should I populate that data into for example, a combo box? Do I need to create a separate data store and push the data from my recursive function in it and then link the Combobox's store to it?

Also, how to get the "current workspace name" (workspace that I am working in, inside Rally), in Rally SDK 2.0rc1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'context' config option to specify which project level to start at and add 'projectScopeDown' to make sure child projects are returned. That would look something like this:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    limit : Infinity,
    model : 'Project',      
    fetch : ['Name','ObjectID'],
    context : {
        project : '/project/' + PROJECT_OID,
        projectScopeDown : true
    }
}).load({
    callback: function(store) {
        //Use project store data here
    }
});
```

To get your current context data, use: `this.getContext()`.

```
var workspace = this.getContext().getWorkspace();
var project = this.getContext().getProject();
```

Comment: This is my current code (the combobox returns 0 results which is incorrect) ,http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6327076/  . I tried your code inside rally but it doesn't narrow down to my currently selected project. I also tried writing `context: this.getContext()` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: @nickm, I also tried using this, http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6330138/ . This time, I get all projects and workspaces, seems like the context is not doing anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you try exposing with console.log the this.getContext().getWorkspace() and this.getContext().getProject() you may understand better what is returned and what is required. In one of my cases I had to use this.getContext().getProject().project.
Using console debug statement is best way to figure what you need based on its usage.